# XNA 2D Camera - How to make it properly follow sprite

Tags: c#, camera, xna, 2d, sprite

## Hello there wonderful people!

Let's just cut to  the chase. 
I've made a tile engine that draws my map relative to my camera (The tiles that are drawn are the ones visible in the camera window), and i've made a sprite (my character) that is centered within the camera.
Whenever i move the camera my character follows accordingly, the only problem is when i reach the borders of my map. Programing the way i did has constrained my camera from moving beyond the borders, resulting in limiting my character from moving closer to the borders(since it's always centered within the camera).

How do i free my camera from the restraints of my evil map?

p.s. I've made a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHNlu.jpg) to illustrate what i want to do.
And here is the [guide](http://www.xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=Tutorial:TileEngineSeries:1) i followed.

### Here's my code where i draw the tiles and place the camera:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        Vector2 firstSquare = new Vector2(Camera.Location.X / Tile.TileWidth, Camera.Location.Y / Tile.TileHeight);
        int firstX = (int)firstSquare.X;
        int firstY = (int)firstSquare.Y;

        Vector2 squareOffset = new Vector2(Camera.Location.X % Tile.TileWidth, Camera.Location.Y % Tile.TileHeight);
        int offsetX = (int)squareOffset.X;
        int offsetY = (int)squareOffset.Y;

        for (int y = 0; y < squaresDown; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < squaresAcross; x++)
            {
                foreach (int tileID in myMap.Rows[y + firstY].Columns[x + firstX].BaseTiles)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(
                        Tile.TileSetTexture,
                        new Rectangle(
                            (x * Tile.TileWidth) - offsetX, (y * Tile.TileHeight) - offsetY,
                            Tile.TileWidth, Tile.TileHeight),
                        Tile.GetSourceRectangle(tileID),
                        Color.White);
                }
            }
        }

        spriteBatch.End();
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

### And here is the code where i move the camera:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        IsMouseVisible = true;
        KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            Camera.Location.X = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.X - 2, 0, (myMap.MapWidth - squaresAcross) * Tile.TileWidth);
        }

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            Camera.Location.X = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.X + 2, 0, (myMap.MapWidth - squaresAcross) * Tile.TileWidth);
        }

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            Camera.Location.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.Y - 2, 0, (myMap.MapHeight - squaresDown) * Tile.TileHeight);
        }

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            Camera.Location.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.Y + 2, 0, (myMap.MapHeight - squaresDown) * Tile.TileHeight);
        }
        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: when camera reach edge, then move character instead. or add some offset where you catch key pressing (ex: `myMap.MapWidth - squaresAcross + offset`) so camera will move further.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making your player follow the camera, you need to make your camera follow the player.  That way you can set restrictions on the camera, instead of attempting to hack the camera system to make the character do things.

On every update, you would have something like:

```
Player.Update(gametime);
Camera.Update(Player.Position);
```

Comment: While trying your solution i noticed another flaw with my program. Whenever my camera moves outside the border the program attempts to draw tiles with a negative index, causing the game to crash. Can i get help here, or should i post a new qestion?

Comment: This is happening because you are indexing a negative value when you get to negative camera coordinates.  You are assuming, that your map always starts at 0,0, so the easiest way to fix this would be to not process the negative coordinates at all.

Init like this:   int firstY = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(firstSquare.Y, 0, squaresDown);

int firstX = (int)MathHelper.Clamp(firstSquare.X, 0, squaresAcross);

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, i really appreciate it. But even after applying your code my program still slaps an [error code](http://gyazo.com/eae0372213eea7f569b5bf1038012bcf) in my face.
I figured that something was still giving it a negative value, so i tried adding [this](http://gyazo.com/088c259e81be23e1bba91ce5240f7913) code which, in the end, turned out to be no help at all.

Comment: The translation to the error code is: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name